# Wrong Size and Position After Importing in Cities Skylines

Tags: export, import

I used Blender in Mac OS to create a model for Cities Skylines game. The final model is like that.

[image]

But when I import the model in Cities Skylines, the preview is like that.

[image]

Any help?

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! Did you scale your model? If so and your scale isn't at default (1/1/1) then press Strg+A and select Scale

Comment: I fixed the scale like that and now the proportions and the location are correct, but the model is very small. I set the scene units to metric 1.000, the model dimensions are x 16m, y 4m and z 4m and when I export the model to fbx I put the scale to 1.0.

Comment: I attached the new screenshot in the original question. Theoretically a square in the game is 8x8 meters.

Answer (score 0):

To fix that with Blender v2.77 is necessary to check the "EXPERIMENTAL Apply transform" option.

[image]

Comment: It's better to apply and freeze transforms in Blender to be sure that everything is exported as it was created